# ImportError: cannot import name 'keras' from 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm try learning TensorFlow but i have a problem. I'm importing TensorFlow like in official website but i take a error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Koray\Desktop\Python\main.py", line 4, in

from tensorflow import keras

ImportError: cannot import name 'keras' from 'tensorflow'

(C:\Users\Koray\Desktop\Python\tensorflow.py)

Comment: Don't name your script `tensorflow.py`.  Your import finds that script instead of the real one.

Comment: Oww, I forgot about that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For community benefit, adding @John Gordon answer here in the answer section.

> Don't name your script `tensorflow.py`. Your import finds that script instead of the real one.

Instead you can name any other for example `learning.py`. Now all your imports work as expected.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```